# Avoid "Aborted (core dump)" error when using grep -Pe and regex to find images?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am writing a bash-script that should move all the generated versions of a picture to another folder, i.e. original-image.jpg should not be moved, but original-image-120x240.jpg and original-image-1920x1080.jpg should be moved.

However, my script fails at this command:

```
find image-folder/ -type f | grep -Pe '-(\d{2,4})x(\d{2,4})\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)'
```

With

```
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What am I doing wrong here? What is the reason for the "Aborted (core dumped)"? Out of memory?

Are there other ways to accomplish what I want, that would help me avoid this error?

I am running this on CentOS.

Comment: try `find image-folder/ -type f -exec grep -P '-(?:\d{2,4})x(?:\d{2,4})\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)' {} \;`

Comment: What is output of `echo 'foo-11x22.jpg' | grep -Pe '-(\d{2,4})x(\d{2,4})\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)'`

Comment: Try `grep image-folder -Pre '-(\d{2,4})x(\d{2,4})\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)'`, no need to use `find` for such tasks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your files in the directory belong to either originals or resized, you can find the resized images with `find` itself.

```
find image-folder/ -type f -regex '.*-[1-9][0-9]*x[1-9][0-9]*\.(jpe?g|png|gif)'
```

Comment: I had to add --regextype posix-extended to make this work. I also made the regex less greedy with [0-9]{1,3}. Now I don't get core dump errors anymore. Do you know why I got that?

Comment: Nope, cannot repro here, but I'm guessing CentOS has some really old version of GNU coreutils.